# run octave script from command window with variable length arguments

Tags: octave

I have a octave script (**script.m**) file with the following code:

```
if length(argv()) > 0
     s = argv(){1};
else
     s = "";
```

In octave command window, pwd is set to the script directory. From command window, how can I run script.m with one, two or no arguments?

I am using Octave (GUI) in windows.

Answer (score 1):

An `endif` is missing at the end but here we go:

```
if length(argv()) > 0
  s = argv(){1};
else
  s = "";
endif
s
```

With no argument:

```
$ octave script.m
s =
```

With one argument:

```
$ octave script.m foobar
s = foobar
```

With two arguments (the second goes to nirvana because you don't use it in your script):

```
$ octave script.m foobar baz
s = foobar
```

Comment: I am using Octave (GUI) in windows. Here it says that 'octave' is undefined

Comment: If you browse to your Octave installation folder (I guess it's c:\Octave) you'll'' find a octave-cmd.bat or vbs. 'octave´ should run from these directly. If you want to run octave from a windows "cmd" window you'll have to set the PATH so that it includes the /bin directory. Have a look at the before mentionen .bat and .vbs, they show you how to set it

Comment: actually, I was using octave.bat. The error that I am getting is from that window.